# How do I get an image and paragraph to wait before showing up after clicking for web development

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some lag time from when an one of my images is clicked to when the image and accompanying paragraph show up. In my code, you see the four images. When you click on them, an expanded version of the image and a paragraph shows up. I want it so after you click on an image, there is a lag time of about one second between your click and the image-paragraph duo showing up, but I only want this to happen for the first click on any image. For the second click on any image, I want it to show up instantaneously. I'm new to programming and I'm having a lot of trouble with this. I would love any help I can get. Let me know if you guys need more info. Thanks

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
  imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

.yeep1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.yeep2 {
  color: purple;
}

.yeep3 {
  color: green;
}
.yeep4 {
  color: blue;
}

.yeep1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep1'> Parapraph #1 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new function that checks the click count. If first click, setTimeout for 1s.

```
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

    if(click == 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            myFunction(imgs);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        myFunction(imgs);
    }

    click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

        var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
        expandImg.src = imgs.src;
        var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
        imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

        expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
        imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';

}
```

https://jsbin.com/potakiw/edit?js,output

Comment: I'm trying to use your code, but whenever I add to it stops working. I explain it more at the top of my HTML code here: https://jsfiddle.net/rfradkin/eq2h50kg/1/   Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Sure. So you want it to click, wait while animation runs, then remove the timeout? Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpusx631/

Answer (score 0):

I've added a check to make the function know if it needs to wait, if not you can click and render immediately, else (on the first click) we wait 1 second before rendering anything

```js
var doineedtowait = 0;
function myFunction(imgs) {
  if(doineedtowait == 0){
  sleep(1000);
  }
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
  imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
  doineedtowait++; //after executing we update the doineedtowait to +1 
  //so the if with sleep for 1 second will not be used anymore
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}

.yeep1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.yeep2 {
  color: purple;
}

.yeep3 {
  color: green;
}
.yeep4 {
  color: blue;
}

.yeep1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep1'> Parapraph #1 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```